# Understanding priorities in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

We want to change the properties of an input tag, wait a little, then change the properties back:

```
    $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
        .val('Danke. Wir melden uns gleich!')
        .css({'background' : 'none'})
        .css({'border' : 'none'})
        .css({'color' : '#fff'});
    $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
        .delay(3000);       
    $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
        .val('')
        .css({'border' : '1px solid #fff'})
        .css({'color' : '#525353'})
        .css({'background' : '#fff'});
```

Thanks in advance for any tips on what we're doing wrong here!

Comment: That is not where you use `delay` which is used in animation queues, use setTimeout instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) instead of `delay`, [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) works on animation queues.

```
var $input = $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
        .val('Danke. Wir melden uns gleich!')
        .css({'background' : 'none'})
        .css({'border' : 'none'})
        .css({'color' : '#fff'});
window.setTimeout(function(){
       $input.val('')
        .css({'border' : '1px solid #fff'})
        .css({'color' : '#525353'})
        .css({'background' : '#fff'});
}, 3000);
```

> .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed;

As an alternate approach instead of setting inline style with `css` add/remove classes.

```
.withValue{
   background : none;
   border : none;
   color : #fff;
   /*Rules*/
}

.withOutValue{
   background : #fff;
   border : 1px solid #fff;
   color : #525353;
   /*Rules*/
}
```

and

```
var $input = $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
        .val('Danke. Wir melden uns gleich!').addClass('withValue');
window.setTimeout(function(){
       $input.val('').addClass('withOutValue').removeClass('withValue');
       //or use toggleClass
       //$input.val('').toggleClass('withOutValue withValue');
});
```

Comment: +1 for adding/removing classes rather than changing multiple inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout.

```
var
    style1 = {'background':'none','border':'none','color':'#fff'},
    style2 = {'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid #fff','color':'#525353'};

$('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]')
    .val('Danke. Wir melden uns gleich!').css(style1);

setTimeout(function(){
    $('input[name=produkt-rueckruf-telefon]').css(style2);
},3000);
```